# How to make GlassFish web server use JRuby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, glassfish, port, response

I installed Ubuntu, GlassFish web server, installed JRuby on Rails using GlassFish's admin tools, deployed my application from .war archive. The problem is only - when I attempt to run this web application nothing happens. GlassFish isn't listening on port 8080 as promised. The GlassFish administration web console listens on port 4848 and works fine. What to do to pair GlassFish and JRuby on Rails the correct way, remembering that it isn't a separate JRuby installation?

**Update:** it seems that this problem lies somewhere around access rights because I can deploy an application through

```
sudo ./asadmin deploy
```

but can not do the same through web console. The output is as if the application has been deployed, without any error messages (web interface shows the presence of application, domain folder contains my application's file/folder structure), but something in server's internals isn't bound to application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't think much and applied quick and dirty solution: set "777" access rights to /home/glassfish and all its contents. It helped.